# Is there possibility to debug Commerce Server component based OperationSequenceComponent?

Tags: microsoft-commerce-server

What is correct way to debug Commerce Server component based OperationSequenceComponent ?
Which process should I attach to in order to step into component's methods ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what process is hosting your custom code. Assuming you are running a standard Commerce Server 2009 or Commerce 10 or Commerce 11 based website, you would typically debug w3wp.exe (Assuming you are running a typical Microsoft/Ascentium/SiteCore Commerce Server based website hosted in IIS).

Note that you must first register your custom operation sequence component in your ChannelConfiguration.config file and your web.config. How you do this depends on which version of Commerce Server you are running as the ChannelConfiguration and web.config files changed between Microsoft Commerce Server 2009, 2009 R2, 10 and 11.

Details on how to do it for Microsoft Commerce Server 2009 R2 can be found on MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh597497%28v=cs.95%29.aspx)

If you are getting OperationSequenceComponent errors for SequenceComponents that are "out of the box" and ship with the product, you will not be able to debug them without the source code. Forgive me if that is obvious, but I'm making an attempt to be thorough in this answer.

If you have not already done so take a look at the Application Event Log on the machine where your web site or web service (The calling code) is hosted. OperationSequence errors are logged there by the CommerceFoundation by default and it can be helpful to get innerexception and faultexception detail from the OperationService.

Brad Foley has provided some pointers as well. I'm not recommending reflector or attempting to dissassemble Microsoft / Ascentium / CommerceServer.NET / SiteCore source code. But you can read through his post for some pointers while debugging OperationService errors in Sequence Components [here](http://www.blfoley.com/2011/08/06/trouble-shooting-commerce-server-2009-profile-extensions/)